# is there a way to detect malicious view float upon my foreground application

Tags: android, permissions, virus

In Android, View can be floating upon any activities, when they have the permission android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW. Virus can use this feature to do many things they want.
SO, is there a way to detect these view on my foreground application? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to detect these view on my foreground application?

Not really.

By default, on newer versions of Android (4.0+ IIRC), touch events are either consumed by such views or cannot be seen by those views via callback methods. Earlier versions of Android supported such a floating view both finding out about touch events *and* allowing them to pass along to underlying activities, referred to as a "tapjacking" attack. For API Level 9+, you can use `android:filterTouchesWhenObscured` to control this behavior.